# SQLServer conditional execution within 'EXEC' if a column exists

Tags: sql-server, exec

I'm new to SQLServer scripting (normally being a C++ developer), and would really appreciate a bit of assistance.

I am attempting to perform a "find and replace" update on all tables in a SQLServer database that contain a 'PROJID' column.  I am really struggling to find a way to do this that doesn't report to me:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'PROJID'.

The statement I am executing is:

```
EXEC
(
  'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = N''PROJID'' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N''' + @TableName + '''))' +
  ' BEGIN' +
  ' UPDATE ' + @TableName + 
  ' SET ' + @ColumnName + ' = REPLACE(' + @ColumnName + ',''' + @ReplaceIDStr + ''',''' + @FindIDStr + ''')' +
  ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ''' + @ReplaceIDStr + '''' + ' AND PROJID = ''1000''' +
  ' END'
)
```

I have also tried using:

```
'IF COL_LENGTH(''' + @TableName + ''',''PROJID'') IS NOT NULL' +
```

instead of the column-exist check above.  This also still gives me the "Invalid Column Name" messages.

I would be happy to take the column-exist check outside of the 'Exec' statement, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output the results of this query to text. Don't forget to change the values of the variables! Take the result of this and run it.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(200) = 'ReplaceColumn'
    , @ReplaceIdStr VARCHAR(200) = 'ExampleReplaceIdStr'
    , @FindIdStr VARCHAR(200) = 'ExampleFindIdStr'

PRINT 'BEGIN TRAN'
PRINT 'SET XACT_ABORT ON'

SELECT
    'UPDATE ' + C.TABLE_NAME + CHAR(13)
    + 'SET ' + @ColumnName + ' = REPLACE(' + @ColumnName + ', ''' + @ReplaceIdStr + ''', ''' + @FindIdStr + ''')' + CHAR(13)
    + 'WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ''%' + @ReplaceIdStr + '%'' AND PROJID = ''1000''' + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME = 'PROJID'

PRINT 'COMMIT TRAN'

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

EDIT: Also, some reasoning: You said you want update all tables where they contain a column called `PROJID`. Your first query just says that if the table `@TableName` has a `PROJID` column, then update `@ColumnName` on it. But it doesn't guarantee that it has @ColumnName on it. The query I gave doesn't check that either, because I'm assuming that all tables that have `PROJID` also have `@ColumnName`. If that isn't the case, let me know and I can update the answer to check that. That you're getting an `Invalid Column Name` error points to `@ColumnName` not existing.

Your query would have updated one table (`@TableName`) at most, whereas the one I gave you will update every table that has `PROJID`. I hope that's what your going for.

EDIT 2: Here is a version that would run it all at once:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(200) = 'Value'
    , @ReplaceIdStr VARCHAR(200) = 'ExampleReplaceIdStr'
    , @FindIdStr VARCHAR(200) = 'ExampleFindIdStr'


DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE UpdateCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    'UPDATE ' + C.TABLE_NAME
    + ' SET ' + @ColumnName + ' = REPLACE(' + @ColumnName + ', ''' + @ReplaceIdStr + ''', ''' + @FindIdStr + ''')'
    + ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ''%' + @ReplaceIdStr + '%'' AND PROJID = ''1000'''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME = 'PROJID'

OPEN UpdateCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM UpdateCursor
INTO @Sql

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM UpdateCursor
    INTO @Sql
END


CLOSE UpdateCursor
DEALLOCATE UpdateCursor
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy.  That's a novel idea that I'd not come across so far.  I would ideally prefer a one-step operation since I need to send my SQL to a customer to use to fix up their data, but I'll study your approach a bit further as there may be some merit in this.

Comment: @Coder_Dan I added a version that uses a cursor to just go through and execute each update it comes up with. That work a little better? As a note, if you have access to the db in question, you can run the first version, spot check the result, and then send just the resulting script off.

Comment: Sorry, the code that I submitted is only a fragment of my SQL.  I have 2 loops in the whole thing, one that is iteratively assigning TableName to each of the tables and another that is iteratively assigning ColumnName to all of the columns in the table.  This is based upon the technique presented on this page: http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2010/02/19/Search+Every+Table+And+Field+In+A+SQL+Server+Database+Updated.aspx
There should be no chance of the @ColumnName not representing a valid column - indeed, when I ran this with a simpler query in the EXEC statement it ran fine.

Comment: @Coder_Dan Using this method you don't have to iterate on table. This will fill the cursor with an update for every table that has a `PROJID` column. The requirement is that every table also have a `@ColumnName` column or it will blow up. If you can't guarantee that, I can add in a protection against that not being the case.

Comment: Thanks again @Jeremy.  You say that you added a version that uses a cursor.  I am not seeing that version at the moment.
I have a copy of the database here, but it's about a month old now, so I wouldn't like to rely upon it.

Comment: @Coder_Dan Can you not see the code under the EDIT 2: header? It's the text added in revision 3 of my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12268444/revisions

Comment: Yeah, I've got your "Edit 2" now, thanks @Jeremy.  I'll give that a try in the morning (I'm in the UK).

Comment: I had a proper look at your "Edit 2" today.  Unfortunately I couldn't work out how to make it work because in my case I need to iterate through all of the columns in each table, rather than having a single column for each table.  If you get chance, I would be fascinated to learn how you might go about this, but it's not urgent because I ended up discovering that I could use EXEC and @@ROWCOUNT to make my original script work.  It's probably a bit of a hack, but it does work.  Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do it in a different scope.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns ...)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
  SET @sql = N'UPDATE ...';
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with my 'TableName' being a runtime variable that is being assigned iteratively to the different tables in my database?

Ie, don't I effectively need to do something like:
IF EXISTS (EXEC ('SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns ...'))

Will this kind of thing work?

Comment: Actually, is the way to do this to use: IF @@RowCount, having used EXEC with a runtime-generated string to look for the existence of the column?